# Firebase Storage Image download not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage

I use the following code to download an image from Firebase storage:

```
storageRef.child(self.fileImageDownloadPath).getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in

    let userPhoto = UIImage(data: data!)

    // ASSIGNS DOWNLOADED PICTURE TO OUTLET
    self.sharedProfileImage.image = userPhoto

    print("– – – Succesfully downloaded the shared profile picture")

}
```

The download path is retrieved successfully from the corresponding Firebase database; however, the app always crashes because of the expression `let userPhoto = UIImage(data: data!)`; the console logs a

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

If I try to use simply `let userPhoto = UIImage(data: data)` a compiler error occurs:

> Value of optional type 'Data?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Do you have any idea how I can solve this? Generally, I am well aware of how to (safely) unwrap optionals – but I can't solve this by myself nonetheless.

Comment: It is quite simple, the data you are providing is not there! Just do a '
if  let error = error {
  } else {
let userPhoto = UIImage(data: data!)

    // ASSIGNS DOWNLOADED PICTURE TO OUTLET
    self.sharedProfileImage.image = userPhoto

    print("– – – Succesfully downloaded the shared profile picture")
  } '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved it:

```
storageRef.child(self.fileImageDownloadPath).getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in

    if (error != nil) {

        print(error!.localizedDescription)

    } else {

        self.sharedProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        print("– – – Succesfully downloaded the shared profile picture")

    }

}
```

With this, I found out that

> Object https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/[...] does not exist

which clearly is because of the missing slash in

> https:/firebase[...]